# How can I convert a json string to a json array using Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I am using this code to read a json file `firstSession.json` and display it on a label.

```
var assembly = typeof(ScenarioPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
string jsonFileName = "firstSession.json";
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) 
{
    var json = reader.ReadToEnd(); //json string
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionModel>(json);
    foreach (SessionModel scenario in data)
    {
        scenarioName.Text = scenario.title; 
        break;
    }
    scenarioName.Text = data.title; // scenarioName is the name of the label

}
```

`SessionModel.cs` looks like:

```
    public class SessionModel : IEnumerable
    {
        public int block { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int numberMissing { get; set; }
        public string word1 { get; set; }
        public string word2 { get; set; }
        public string statement1 { get; set; }
        public string statement2 { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
        public string positive { get; set; } // positive answer (yes or no)
        public string negative { get; set; } // negative answer (yes or no) 
        public string answer { get; set; } // positive or negative 
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string immersion { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

The beginning of my json is:

```
{
  "firstSession": [
    {
      "block": 1,
      "name": "mark",
      "title": "mark's house",
      "numberMissing": 1,
      "word1": "distracted",
      "word2": "None",
      "statement1": "string 1",
      "statement2": "None",
      "question": "question",
      "positive": "No",
      "negative": "Yes",
      "answer": "Positive",
      "type": "Social",
      "format": "Visual",
      "immersion": "picture"
    },
```

I am getting a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type "MyProject.SessionModel" because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'firstSession', line 2, position 17.`

How can I convert the json string to a json array? Or make one of the other modifications the debugger suggests?

Comment: ```public class ScenarioObjects : IEnumerable
    {
        public List<SessionModel> scenarios { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }``` I tried this as well, while making ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScenarioObjects>(json);``` and I got the same error.

Comment: why does Root need to be IEnumerable?  And why are you calling it "scenarios", the name of the json attribute is "firstSession"

Comment: I changed it to firstSession (see my reply to your answer). If it is not IEnumerable, data in the foreach loop underlines in red and is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a wrapper class (json2csharp.com will help you do this)

```
public class Root    {
    public List<SessionModel> firstSession { get; set; } 
}
```

then

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

`data.firstSession` will be a `List<SessionModel>`

Comment: I just tried: ```public class Root : IEnumerable
    {
        public List<SessionModel> firstSession { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }``` and changed the type to Root, but I got the same exception. Could it be due to the IEnumerable interface? If it is not implemented, data underlines in red and is null.

Comment: you are not iterating Root, you are iterating firstSession, which is a List

Comment: `foreach (SessionModel scenario in data.firstSession)`

Comment: Just tried this, I am getting the same exception except with ```Path 'firstSession[0].block', line 4, position 14```

Comment: Sorry-- I deleted IEnumerable in SessionModel, and it worked! Thank you so much for all your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new Class and have firstSession as List of SessionModel.

   ```
    public class Sessions
    {
        public List<SessionModel> firstSession { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Remove IEnumerable from the SessionModel

   public class SessionModel
   {
   public int block { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }

   }
3. Change thedeserialization part as follows

   var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(line);
   foreach (SessionModel scenario in data.firstSession)
   {
   //Here you can get each sessionModel object
   Console.WriteLine(scenario.answer);

   }